# Symfony 3 web front controller with env

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

Symfony 3 uses two web front controllers app.php and app_dev.php. How could I change it to use one controller with usage of env variables to set the env (prod, dev) and debug.

I've tried to remove the app_dev.php but symfony tries to load that file.

Maybe this is not the way to do it, just learning symfony. Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Symfony does not enforce entrypoints (app/app_dev) locations. Could you tell us what errors you encountered?

Comment: The front controllers are stored in the web directory. What I wise, is to use one front controller with the possibilty to set the environment through env variables. So i've removed the dev controller but somewhere symfony tries to load this file

Answer (score 0):

The frontend controller files `app.php` and `app_dev.php` exist as examples of `prod` and `dev` respectively. As the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/environments.html) suggests, you'll want to remove one or the other for your production deployment, or simply create a custom frontend controller for each environment, and have your `apache` or `nginx` configuration only load the appropriate file to launch Symfony.

You'll see in the file, the environment is declared and passed along with whether or not debug should be enabled.

```
//dev environment, with debug enabled
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

By contrast, for production:

```
//prod environment, debug disabled
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

If you want a single controller with some dynamic elements, I'd recommend removing `app_dev.php` and using `app.php` with custom logic before `AppKernel` is instantiated to do what you want.

Comment: But when I remove one file I get Some errors. Looks like symfony is expecting thouse files. I'II post the errors tomorrow

Comment: You'll only get an error for removing a file if that file is what `apache` or `nginx` are expecting as the default index page.

Comment: When i delete the file app_dev.php this is what i get on screen:
No input file specified. Like @Jake Litwicki said its configured somewhere in my nginx (vagrant homestead symfony). But where could i find these settings to change to only use app.php